# Problema com select em KnockoutJS e MooTools

Tags: javascript, knockoutjs, mootools

Estou tendo um problema em um teste simples com KnockoutJS em conjunto com o MooTools:

```html
<div>
    <select data-bind="foreach: animais">
        <option data-bind="text: nome, value: id"></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

```js
var Animal = new Class({
    initialize: function(id, nome) {
        this.self = this;
        self.id = id;
        self.nome = nome;
    }
});

viewModel = new Class({
    initialize: function(animais) {
        this.self = this;
        self.animais = animais;
    }
});

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel([
    new Animal(1, "Cachorro"),
    new Animal(2, "Gato"),
    new Animal(3, "Macaco")
]));
```

Rodem no JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p6nyr4nq/1/

Curiosamente, o select contêm "Macaco" repetido 3 vezes.

Comment: Andrey, o certo seria usar o `bindingHandler` `options`, tentei usar aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/p6nyr4nq/6/, mas como não conheço o Mootools, não sei como funciona a criação e organização do seu `ViewModel`...

Comment: Pode explicar melhor o que quer fazer? Você está a exportar o `self` para o espaço global... o seu uso da Classe de MooTools não está correto. Se explicar melhor pode dar para ajudar...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O certo como eu disse, é usar o [`BindingHandler` de `options`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) em um `select`.

O seu HTML ficaria mais reduzido:

```
<div>
    <select data-bind="options: animais, optionsText: 'nome', optionsValue: 'id'" />
</div>
```

Os parâmetros `optionsText` e `optionsValue` são respectivamente as propriedades do objeto para o texto e o valor do `option` que será gerado.

Seu JavaScript ficará quase o mesmo, só que o fato de usar `this.self = this;` estava quebrando a estrutura interna do objeto. Com um pequeno acerto fica:

```
var Animal = new Class({
    initialize: function(id, nome) {
        var self = this;

        self.id = id;
        self.nome = nome;
    }
});

var viewModel = new Class({
    initialize: function(animais) {
        var self = this;
        self.animais = ko.observableArray(animais);
    }
});

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel([
    new Animal(1, "Cachorro"),
    new Animal(2, "Gato"),
    new Animal(3, "Macaco")
]));
```

Segue o [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p6nyr4nq/9/) com o exemplo.

Comment: Não seria melhor usar o `this` da Classe em vez de o indicar via `self`? Assim: http://jsfiddle.net/p6nyr4nq/10/ (`+1`)

Comment: Poderia ser. Não sei o que ele irá fazer com o `self` depois. Chuto que o uso do `self` seria posterior, por exemplo numa função de evento, onde o `this` é o `Binding Context`, não o objeto em si. Mas nesse caso teria que mudar o `this.self = this` para `this.eu_mesmo = this`;

Comment: Vou aguardar também para perceber o que o Andrey pretende e dar mais sugestões se necessário. Fico contente de ver perguntas com MooTools a aparecerem por aqui.

Comment: Wakim e @Sergio Desculpem a demora. Não pude conferir o resultado ainda pois o JSFiddle saiu do ar. Mas já vi que o erro era a questão do this/self mesmo. O único motivo porque usei o `self` é porque os [tutoriais oficiais o usam](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=collections). Se existe um jeito de fazer isso com o MooTools, com certeza não é do jeito que eu tentei. =)

Comment: @Andrey no MooTools o `this` é tratado de maneira especial no sentido a que ele refere-se à Classe e o método initialize é o construtor da Classe. Assim usar o `this` dentro do initialize é o mais lógico e mais fácil de ler.

Comment: @Andrey, a resposta do Wakim está correta. Se ela resolveu o seu problema pode marcar como aceite.

Comment: @Sergio Entendi. Só quando você disse "se refere à classe", na verdade quis dizer "se refere à ***instância*** da classe", não? Marquei a resposta do Wakim como correta, e obrigado pelo esclarecimento. =)

Comment: @Andrey exato :)